# requests.get returns 403 in ec2 instance while the same url works in local host

Tags: python, request

I'm trying to request a url but I'm receiving 403 as return when I run it from my EC2 instance. But I get a 200 when I run form my localhost:

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.americanas.com.br/categoria/eletrodomesticos/freezer/vertical'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'}
requests.get(url,verify=False,headers=headers)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Propably an ip ban. Try with a proxy If you have a reliable proxy server.

Comment: @t.m.adam I'm trying with several proxies, but I'm always getting 403. Are there other possibilites?

Comment: The page redirects to HTTPS, do you have an HTTPS proxy in your proxies dictionary?

Comment: Also, have you tested if those proxies work in your local machine? If you're using free proxies note that they may also be blacklisted.

Comment: I changed the ip from the ec2 instance and it worked